# Перебор значений масива

Tags: javascript

Нужно, в этом цикле:

```
for (var i = 1, n = 1; i < 4, n < 4; i++, n++) {
    document.write(Mass1[i] + Mass2[n] + "<br>");
}
```

Сделать так, чтобы выводилось значение i=1; n=1, затем i=1; n=2, затем i=1; n=3, затем i=2; n=1 ну и так далее, не обязательно цикл или только цикл...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
   for (var n = 1; n < 4; n++) {
      document.write("i = " + i + "; n = " + n);
   }
}
```